# Axios authentication request to Drupal - invalid_grant

Tags: drupal, oauth, oauth-2.0, axios

I'm trying to authenticate to Drupal from a JS application using axios.

I can authenticate through Postman and through terminal with curl, but I can't seem to authenticate using axios.

This is what I'm doing:

```
const uri = 'https://test.com/oauth/token'

const data = new FormData();
data.append("client_id", "xxxxxx");
data.append("client_secret", "secret");
data.append("grant_type", "password");
data.append("username", "user");
data.append("password", "secret");
data.append("scope", "");

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: uri,
  headers: {}, 
  data: data
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("res", message);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("error in request", err);
});
```

This is what I'm getting in the console:

```
 data:
  { error: 'invalid_grant',
    error_description:
     'The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.',
    hint: 'Check the configuration to see if the grant is enabled.',
    message:
     'The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.' } } }
```

This is what I'm getting in Drupal:

```
League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue using axios as well, below is what finally worked for me to authenticate against the simple_oauth endpoint in Drupal 8.

```
 import * as axios from 'axios';

 const axiosAPI = axios.create();
 axiosAPI.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost/';
 axiosAPI.defaults.timeout = 30000;

 async authenticate(username, password){
   const params = new URLSearchParams();
   params.append('grant_type',  'password');
   params.append('client_id',  'xxx-yyy-zzz');
   params.append('client_secret', 'somesupersecret');
   params.append('username', username);
   params.append('password', password);

   try{
     let response = await axiosAPI.post('/oauth/token', params);

     console.log(response.data);

   } catch(e){
     console.error(e);
   }
}
```

So the key was to use URLSearchParams to encode the parameters, instead of form encoding the data. This was actually mentioned in the docs at https://github.com/axios/axios under the heading "Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format" once I figured out that I shouldn't just post a form.